# 2's Complement base system

Tags: binary, numbers

I'm doing a question about 2's complement and I was just wandering about the place value of 2's complement. For example, in binary, the place value goes like 1 2 4 8 16 32 and doubles by two. but I'm not sure what the place value is for negative numbers.

The question I've got is asking you that is this number 10110001 was a 2's complement integer what would it be. I under than that you flip the numbers and add one but how can I actullay find the value of this?

Comment: This seems like a question for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2's complement system, the most significant place ("sign bit", though this term causes confusion since it isn't purely a sign) has the weight -2<sup>k</sup> where k is its index, for example for 8 bits:

```
weights: -128 +64 +32 +16 +8 +4 +2 +1
example:    1   1   1   1  1  1  0  0 (0xFC) = -128+64+32+16+8+4 = -4
```